# Why would the baptismal state of a spouse be relevant to whether someone can be confirmed in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, confirmation

I am currently going through the RCIA process and am 4 weeks away from  being confirmed. I was just told by the priest that because my husband and I were married previously (neither in a Catholic Church) that I now need copies of our marriage certificates and a copy of my husbands baptismal certificate. There is no record of my husband being baptised and he is not a practicing catholic. What bearing does this have on me becoming confirmed?

Comment: That would be a better question for the priest.

Comment: No, that's just so they can decide whether the marriage needs convalidation or radical sanation. I'll be able to answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: I think the question is fine. It's about Catholic doctrine/practice on a specific issue. Sans the personal overtones, the question is on-topic.

Comment: One question for you, which has a bearing on my answer: it appears that you are a baptized Catholic, or at least Christian; is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

The Catholic Church is asking for proof that your husband is a baptised Christian, baptism being the "gateway to the sacraments."

> **Can.  849** Baptism, the gateway to the sacraments and necessary for
>   salvation by actual reception or at least by desire, is validly
>   conferred only by a washing of true water with the proper form of
>   words. Through baptism men and women are freed from sin, are reborn as
>   children of God, and, configured to Christ by an indelible character,
>   are incorporated into the Church. ([1](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P2U.HTM))

Without proof, your husband is considered by The Catholic Church *not baptised*, which is a **diriment impediment**. Thus, your marriage is considered invalid.

> **Can.  1086 §1.** A marriage between two persons, one of whom has been
>   baptized in the Catholic Church or received into it and has not
>   defected from it by a formal act and the other of whom is not
>   baptized, is invalid.
>
> **§2.** A person is not to be dispensed from this impediment unless the
>   conditions mentioned in cann. ⇒ [1125](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P41.HTM) and ⇒ [1126](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P41.HTM) have been fulfilled.
>
> **§3.** If at the time the marriage was contracted one party was commonly
>   held to have been baptized or the baptism was doubtful, the validity
>   of the marriage must be presumed according to the norm of ⇒ can. [1060](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P3V.HTM)
>   until it is proven with certainty that one party was baptized but the
>   other was not. ([2](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P3Y.HTM))

Your marriage can be rendered valid by **simple convalidation**...

> **Can.  1156 §1.** To convalidate a marriage which is invalid because of a
>   diriment impediment, it is required that the impediment ceases or is
>   dispensed and that at least the party conscious of the impediment
>   renews consent. ([3](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P46.HTM))

...or by **radical sanation**.

> **Can.  1161 §1.** The radical sanation of an invalid marriage is its
>   convalidation without the renewal of consent, which is granted by
>   competent authority and entails the dispensation from an impediment,
>   if there is one, and from canonical form, if it was not observed, and
>   the retroactivity of canonical effects. ([4](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/__P47.HTM))

Unless your marriage is validated by The Catholic Church, you cannot be confirmed.

> Catholics seeking the sacrament of Confirmation must be married *by the
>   Church*, either by a deacon or priest before receiving the sacrament of
>   Confirmation ([5](http://sacredhearthouston.org/adult-confirmation-requirements-2), *emphases added*)

Your priest should have explained all of this to you. [Here](http://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2013/01/17/cath-marry-non-christian/) is a little more information.

Best wishes.